# Recommended way of subclassing a class while maintaining backwards compatibility

Tags: python, software-design

Here is the scenario. I have a class `Foo` that looks like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

    def method(self):
        if self.prop == PROP_VAL_1:
            do_something()
        elif self.prop == PROP_VAL_2:
            do_something_2()
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid value {self.prop}")
```

I want to do a refactor in which I end up with two subclasses of `Foo` like this:

```
class FooA(Foo):
    def method():
        do_something()

class FooB(Foo):
    def method():
        do_something_2()
```

However, the issue is that I can't change how `Foo` is used because there is code currently in use that uses `Foo`. Is it possible to somehow have the superclass `Foo` instantiate objects of type `FooA` and `FooB` depending on the value of `prop`? Another thing I want to avoid is having `Foo` import it's subclasses since this would lead to circular dependencies. Is there some sort of "best practice" for this as well?

Comment: You can convert the `Foo` class to a factory function.

Comment: What would the `__init__` look like in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Rename the `Foo` class, then replace it with a factory function.

```
class NewFoo:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop

class FooA(NewFoo):
    def method():
        do_something()

class FooB(NewFoo):
    def method():
        do_something_2()

def Foo(prop):
    if prop == PROP_VAL_1:
        return FooA(prop)
    elif prop == PROP_VAL_2:
        return FooB(prop)
```

Comment: This doesn't work completely since classes aren't just functions. What if someone is using the line of code `isinstance(fooObject, Foo)`? This change would then break backwards compatibility.

Comment: That's true, this is only a partial solution. You also can't access class attributes as `Foo.attr`. Is there a way to solve it using metaclasses?

Comment: Using metaclasses isn't an ideal solution for me even if it does the job, mostly because I don't entirely understand them, but also because most tutorials I find online about them seem to recommend avoiding metaclasses entirely.

“Metaclasses are deeper magic than 99% of users should ever worry about. If you wonder whether you need them, you don’t (the people who actually need them know with certainty that they need them, and don’t need an explanation about why).”

— Tim Peters

Comment: Maybe you can use `def __new__()` in the `Foo` class as the factory method. But that could cause infinite recursion because creating `FooA` will try to call `Foo.__new__()`

Comment: See https://iscinumpy.gitlab.io/post/factory-classmethods-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

By definition, you want the class `Foo` to return an instance that is not `Foo`, but a subclass of `Foo`.

I would caution against this, as it may be surprising to the users of your class.

You have a few options:

You can use a factory function, as @Barmar suggests but use a name such as `foo_factory` and keep the method `Foo.method` intact with some aggressive logging. This allows you to incrementally change all call sites from `Foo` to `foo_factory` and have the logging as peace of mind that no one is directly instantiating `Foo` anymore.

Another option is to modify `Foo.__new__` to return an instance of a subclass:

I modified your code a bit to an MRE.

```
PROP_VAL_1 = 1
PROP_VAL_2 = 2


class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, prop):
        # if the class was instantiated directly
        if cls is Foo:
            if prop == PROP_VAL_1:
                return FooA(prop)
            elif prop == PROP_VAL_2:
                return FooB(prop)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid value {prop}")
        # this is only reached if a subclass is instantiated
        return super().__new__(cls)
    
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop


class FooA(Foo):
    def method(self):
        return 'do_something'


class FooB(Foo):
    def method(self):
        return 'do_something_2'


foo = Foo(prop=2)
print(isinstance(foo, Foo)) # True
print(type(foo)) # <class '__main__.FooB'>
print(foo.method()) # do_something_2
```